# How to change font size of a paragraph with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm learning JavaScript and I'm trying to change the font size of a paragraph with 3 buttons in a site. While I was writing the code the console output this error and I can't figure out what it is. I also want to know if the way I'm coding it is correct?

The html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html leng="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Mi ejercicio DHTML</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilos.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/codigo.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="parrafo">
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to.
        </p>
        <span class="boton" id="boton1">Fuente pequeña</span>
        <span class="boton" id="boton2">Fuente mediana</span>
        <span class="boton" id="boton3">Fuente grande</span>
    </body>
</html>
```

The CSS:

```
p {
    font-size: 13px;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
}
.boton {
    background: red;
    padding: .5em 1em;
}
```

The JavaScript:

```
window.addEventListener('load', inicio, false);

function inicio() {
    var indice = [1, 2, 3];
    for (var i = 0; i < indice.length; i++) {
        var boton = document.getElementById('boton' + indice[i]);
        boton.addEventListener('click', cambiarFuente, false);
    };
}

function cambiarFuente() {
    console.log('hola');
}
```

and finally the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addEventListener' of null codigo.js:6

I placed the `<script>` tag before `</body>` and now its working; at least that's what I think. Another problem has emerged and its that the paragraph doesn't change its font size but I still receive the console log message as if its working:

```
window.addEventListener('load', inicio, false);

function inicio(){
var indice =[1,2,3];
for (var i = 0; i < indice.length; i++) {
    var boton = document.getElementById('boton' + indice[i]);
    boton.addEventListener('click', cambiarFuente, false);
};

function cambiarFuente(){
    var parrafo = document.getElementById('parrafo');
    parrafo.style.fontSize=20;
    console.log('hola');
}
}
```

I also have no idea of how to assign different font sizes to each button! Can anyone suggest me something?

Comment: i want to use 1 loop to add the event listener to the 3 buttons i would also like to use a loop to make the funciton cmabiarFuente change the fonts

Comment: addEventListener is not supported in IE, have you tried in other browsers.

Comment: im actually testing in chrome :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this way instead of:

```
window.addEventListener('load', inicio, false);
```

Use this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    inicio();
});
```

And in the function:

```
function inicio(){
    var indice =[1,2,3];
    for (var i = 0; i < indice.length; i++) {
        var boton = $('#boton' + indice[i]);
        boton.click(function(){
            cambiarFuente();
        });
    }
}
```

The reason why your script didn't work is, you are executing the script even before the document loads. One **simple fix** would be placing your `<script></script>` before the `</body>` and it works. Check it out.

Comment: is that jquery right? ....im trying to do it exclusivly in javascript in roder to learn :/

Comment: @JhonnatanGonzalezRodriguez Yes. Also, I have given you the explanation of why your script doesn't work. One **simple fix** would be placing your `<script></script>` before the `</body>` and it works. Check it out.

Comment: that worked for me! cool! but i tought that even if i placed the <script></script> in the head it will work because of the window.onload

Comment: Window OnLoad and Document Ready are different. :)

Comment: i now have this but the fontsize is still not changing, but im reciving the ocnsole log message do u know why is that happening?

    window.addEventListener('load', inicio, false);

    function inicio(){
    var indice =[1,2,3];
    for (var i = 0; i < indice.length; i++) {
        var boton = document.getElementById('boton' + indice[i]);
        boton.addEventListener('click', cambiarFuente, false);
    };

    function cambiarFuente(){
        var parrafo = document.getElementById('parrafo');
        parrafo.style.fontSize=20;
        console.log('hola');
    }
}

Comment: @JhonnatanGonzalezRodriguez Change it this way: `parrafo.style.fontSize="20px"`

Answer (score 2):

When document.getElementById returns null, it means it didn't find an element with the supplied ID. In this case, it's because your script is running before the page is loaded.

Call the function after the load event:

```
window.onload = function() {
   // stuff to run onload
};
```

An extra precaution is to check that getElementById returns an element (or at least something other than null) before trying to call a method.

#### Edit

Also, as pointed out by Mahesh Sapkal, IE less than 8 (and maybe 9?) doesn't support `addEventListener`, you have to use `attachEvent`. There are a number of "addEvent" functions that use one or the other based on feature detection, here's a simple one:

```
  function addListener(element, event, fn) {

    // Use addEventListener if available
    if (element.addEventListener) {
      element.addEventListener(event, fn, false);

    // Otherwise use attachEvent, set this and event
    } else if (element.attachEvent) {
      element.attachEvent('on' + event, (function (el) {
        return function() {
          fn.call(el, window.event);
        };
      }(element)));

      // Break closure and primary circular reference to element
      element = null;
    }
  }
```

and the loop becomes:

```
var boton;

for (var i = 0; i < indice.length; i++) {
    boton = document.getElementById('boton' + indice[i]);

    if (boton) {
          addListener(boton, 'click', cambiarFuente);
    }
}
```

Note there is no semicolon after the if block, it's not a statement (though it usually contains statements).

Comment: i was doing some courses and they suggested to use an eventlistener like window.addEventListener('load', function, false) in order to do that, when i was doing the exercise i ddnt have this problem, but im getting it now, do u probabbly know the reasson?

Comment: i also tried the solution but i keep getting the same error :/

Comment: You can use addEventListener too (noting limitations with IE), I was just keeping it simple and similar to what you already had.